# How do I prevent expansion when I use a pattern as argument to a script?

Tags: bash, scripting

I need a very simple script which does this:

```
mogrify -resize $1x$2^ -gravity center -crop $1x$2+0+0 $3
```

so that I can call it in this way:

```
cropresize.sh 110 110 *.png
```

the problem is that the shell expands the `*.png` pattern instead of passing it as it is to the script.

How can I achieve this (script, alias or any other equivalent solution is fine)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the shell performs glob expansion before the arguments are handed over to the command, there's no way I can think of to do it transparently: it's either controlled by the user (quote the parameter) or brute-force (disable globbing completely for your shell with `set -o noglob`).

You're looking at the problem from the wrong end. Change your script to accept multiple filename arguments:

```
x=$1
y=$2
shift 2
mogrify -resize ${x}x${y}^ -gravity center -crop ${x}x${y}+0+0 "$@"
```

Comment: After some thought I came to this conclusion but I couldn't find how to specify "the rest of the arguments after the first two", I was just missing `shift` :)

Comment: For the record you can disable globbing for the specific shell script being run by simply adding `set -o noglob` at the beginning of the script. That will make it possible to pass arguments without expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
cropresize.sh 110 110 \*.png
```

But I can only see zsh (not bash) expanding it like you say.

Comment: Well I can even enclose the argument in single quotes like `'*.png'` but I'd really like it to be completely transparent as if it were a builtin command

Comment: Are you using bash or some other shell? Because in bash what you ask works, but in zsh (which I use) even `echo *.png` tries expanding to all png files.